# How can I select a row based on mutiple max column values?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a few tables which i have all left joined to "table 1" as it has the device IDS.

```
D_ID | U_ID |
1    |  100 
2    | 101
3    | 102
```

I then left join it with table 2 and table 3 which contain the order information and product specifics respectively

Table 2-

```
O_id | order_date | D_id
10       | 2018-2-3 |  1
10       | 2019-5-4 |  1
11       | 2017-1-6 |  2
11       | 2019-2-8 |  2
12       | 2018-10-3 |  3
```

Table 3-

```
 P_ID     | START_DATE | END_DATE | D_ID
 20       | 2018-5-3   | 2018-6-3 | 1
 21       | 2019-6-8   | 2019-6-13| 1
 22       | 2017-2-8   | 2017-2-8 | 2
 23       | 2019-4-2   | 2019-5-2 | 2
 24       | 2018-11-1  | 2018-11-3| 3
```

My output should be able to group by the D_ID and select the entire row which has the maximum order_date and the maximum start_date.

expected output-

```
D_ID     |U_ID  |O_ID  | ORDER_DATE | START_DATE | END_DATE | P_ID
1        |100   |10    | 2019-5-4   | 2019-6-8   | 2019-6-13 | 21
2        |101   |11    | 2019-2-8   | 2019-4-2   | 2019-5-2  | 23
3        |103   |12    | 2018-10-3  | 2018-11-1  | 2018-11-3 | 24



SELECT T1.D_ID, T1.u_id,
       T2.ORDER_DATE, t2.o_id,
       t3.start_date, t3.end_date, t3.P_ID
FROM t1 left JOIN
     t3
     ON t3.d_id = t1.d_id left JOIN
     t2 ON t2.d_id = t1.d_id
where t2.order_date in (select max(order_date) from t2 group by d_id
                       ) and
      t3.start_date in (select max(start_date) from t3 group by d_id
                       )
group by t1.d_id;
```

However the problem I am facing is the mismatch in column values, it does not take the entire row where I have both the max order date and start date.

Comment: i would advice you to read how [MySQL Handles GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) as your GROUP BY usage does not look correct here unless functionally dependency could be used by MySQL..

Comment: share mysql version and sample data and expected output

Comment: Mysql server version is 8.0.17 
I have shared the expected output above

Answer (score 0):

You want correlated subqueries, not `IN`:

```
where t2.order_date = (select max(t2.order_date) 
                       from t2
                       where t2.d_id = t1.d_id
                      ) and
     t3.start_date = (select max(t3.start_date)
                      from t3 
                      where t3.d_id = t1.d_id
                     )
```

This gets the maximum value *per `d_id`*.  Your method is just listing all the maximum values for all `d_id`s and then comparing them to *all* dates.  So, the comparison might match for a *different* `d_id`.